# Covert 2D array in string to 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I feel stupid for asking this question. I have a 2D array in a string like this:

```
var data = "[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f'],['x', 'y', 'z']]";
```

and I'm trying to convert it to

```
var dimensional_array = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f'],['x', 'y', 'z']];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: You could do something like: `const dimensional_array = data.split("],[");`  By no means is that "complete" .. Just an example of breaking the string apart.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "long way" to achieve what you are looking to do.   I first tear the string apart by:

1. Removing the brackets at the beginning of the string
2. Removing the brackets at the end of the string
3. split the array into 3 parts using `data.split("],[");`
4. Loop through the array (now in 3 pieces)
5. Create a temp string and remove single quotes
6. Split second dimension by comma creating `temp_arr`
7. Push final result of second dimension to `final_arr`

```js
var data = "[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f'],['x', 'y', 'z']]";

data = data.substring(2);
data = data.slice(0, -2);

const dimensional_array = data.split("],[");

const final_arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < dimensional_array.length; i++) {
  var temp_string = dimensional_array[i];
  
  temp_string = temp_string.replace(/'/g, "");
  
  const temp_arr = temp_string.split(", ");
  
  final_arr.push(temp_arr);
 
}


    console.log(final_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the string contained in `data` to represent a JavaScript array, you could evaluate it using the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) constructor, i.e. in your case:

```js
var dimensional_array = Function(`return(${data})`)();
```

Since this is intrinsically an unsafe operation (similarly to `eval`), it should not be used if the contents of `data` could be potentially controlled by an external source (like user input, the result of an API call, etc.).
Also note that some websites block the use of the `Function` constructor with [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) headers.

```js
var data = "[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f'],['x', 'y', 'z']]";

var dimensional_array = Function(`return(${data})`)();

console.log(dimensional_array);
```